# input field won't size correctly

Tags: html, css

i have a really annoying issue with sizing an input field and i don't understand how it works.

I got this code. HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="receipt">
    <p class="location"></p>
    <input type="text" id="checkoutField">

  <div class="checkoutButton">
     <a href="#/checkout">
       <p>some button</p>
     </a>         
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The container got a max width of 480px. And i want both the checkoutButton div and the input field to stretch out to that width limit, while also having a 20px margin on both sides. The elements should also be responsive, which is why they doesnt have a fixed size.

This works fine on the div, but i cant get the input field to work the same..
I made a jsfiddle that includes the CSS code aswell:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7vzod4y/2/)

Why is the input behaving like this and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling margin left & right to individual items, it's better call padding for parent container. 
Chk the Modified code - http://jsfiddle.net/k7vzod4y/3/

```
.receipt {
   padding: 0 20px 24px;
}
.receipt .checkoutButton {
  margin: 0;
}
.receipt #checkoutField {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible easily using CSS3 [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function.
You could set you width to `100% - 40px` to take care of your margins.
Something like this:

```
.receipt #checkoutField {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #35aba2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

You can see this in action in you updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7vzod4y/5/)

Comment: Thank you. That works aswell, actually never seen the calc function before.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at your code example I would use the following method. I used the following on the JSFiddle you linked and it worked as you mentioned you wanted it to.

Set the width of the input field to 100%:

```
.receipt #checkoutField {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #35aba2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

And then 100% width on the checkout button as well:

```
.receipt .checkoutButton {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #35aba2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

This method is also responsive because I have used percentages which are related units so they inherit from there parent. So a width of 100% will always stay at the full width of it's parent regardless of the viewport size.

Comment: Been trying this aswell, but as you can see they then extend outside the container. You can see the containers size by the shadows. This is what happens http://jsfiddle.net/k7vzod4y/4/

Comment: It appears to be the margin-left: 20px that is causing the elements inside the container to push out a little. So removing that works.